# Why httpclient has a different behavior (SSL-related) on DO droplet?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, digital-ocean

On my Ubuntu (16.04) dev. env. I can create a default `httpclient` and send a request to an `https` endpoint (e.g. Slack), however, on the prod. env. (DO droplet with Ubuntu 14.04) I get this error :

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

edit : Still trying to figure this out... I guess that DO droplets with Java (Oracle) installed don't have the same certificates than Ubuntu desktop images. I added Slack certificate (got it with this `InstallCert` tool mentioned elsewhere on SO) to the `cacerts` (and ran `update-ca-certificates`) to no avail.

Comment: That is usually indicative of a "transparent" enterprise proxy.

Comment: For the resolution - could you enable the handshake debug?

-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake 
then you will see what is certficates are trusted and what is really received and used

Comment: Still struggling with this, I've updated my OP to reflect my current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Java cacerts might be missing the geotrust root.

You can look at what certificates are trusted by using keytool.
Eg for an oracle JVM:

```
keytool -list -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Look for the entry with the right signature ie:

```
debian:geotrust_global_ca.pem, 18/05/2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): DE:28:F4:A4:FF:E5:B9:2F:A3:C5:03:D1:A3:49:A7:F9:96:2A:82:12
```

If it is not trusted you can install it, download it from:
https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem

Install it with

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem -alias GeoTrust_Global_CA -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Comment: Result: `Certificate already exists in keystore under alias <debian:geotrust_global_ca.pem>`

Comment: I would guess that something on your environment is overwriting the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` location.

Comment: Any idea what could do that ?

Comment: @Rhangaun There are lots of ways to set Java system properties, I would start by checking the value of the property in your app runtime to see what it is set to, then work back from there.

Comment: I was of course overwriting it to access something else, doh !